# Why does the timeout fire before the "click" event loop is complete on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, confirm

Steps:

1. run code in the Firefox
2. wait 5 seconds (important!)
3. Press OK or Cancel
4. expect flag == 0, but it is 10.

```js
var flag;

function myFunction(){
    flag = 0 
    console.info("initial", flag);
    setTimeout(function(){
        flag = 10;
    }, 200);
  
    confirm("conf");
   
    alert("should be 0: "+flag);
}

document.getElementById('button').onclick=myFunction;
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: I waited for 30 seconds, but still it shows 0. Don't tell me now, it should be 5 seconds only. :P

Comment: I think the question is, why does the timeout fire *before the "click" event loop is complete*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because unlike many browsers, Firefox *may* allow the JavaScript thread to run other code while the `alert`, `prompt`, and `confirm` modals are showing, suspending the *current* code. (See end of answer for more on about the "may" in that sentence.) The task where the `alert` etc. was called is suspended, so the code in that task doesn't proceed, but *other* tasks are allowed to run.

This means

- Timers can get their callback
- Ajax completion handlers can run
- Etc.

There's never JavaScript running *concurrently* in two places, but Firefox does let the thread run other tasks while a task is suspended by those modals.

It's an Firefox quirk. I first learned about it right here on Stack Overflow, [thanks to bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2734311/157247).

---

Why I said "may" allow the JavaScript thread to run: It used to be fairly reliable (olders versions of Firefox). I had no trouble replicating it on Firefox 29 or 38. Firefox 42 seems to make it much less likely, but it *does* still happen.

I would expect (though I could be wrong) that Mozilla will change this to be in line with other browsers, as one could argue it violates JavaScript's run-to-completion semantics for tasks, and those semantics just got beefed up and clarified by the latest specification.

Comment: New browser version too? I'm not able to reproduce.

Comment: I can reproduce it on Firefox 42.0 on Windows too.

Comment: @vitalh: Really? I can't (just double-checked). Did you *just* update?

Comment: @vitalh: I just tried a Windows 8.1 system with Firefox **41**, and got 0, not 10. (My Firefox 42 test was on an older version of Windows.)

Comment: @t-j-crowder. No. I update immediately after release.

Comment: @vitalh: Bizarre! I just updated that system to 42, and it still gives me 0, not 10. Are you using my test link above?

Comment: @t-j-crowder. I have checked your test. I still get 10, but sometimes 0.It is unstable.

Comment: @vitalh: What version of Windows? It's completely reliable for me. *Edit* And **just then** I made it happen.

Comment: @t-j-crowder. Windows 7 x64.

Comment: @vitalh: Yes, as I said above, I made it happen on Firefox 42 as well (Windows 8.1 and then on Linux, too). It seems a lot less likely, but apparently Firefox still has this quirk.

Answer (score 1):

I tried [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bLdb1tre/) in both Firefox and in Chrome. In Firefox I got `10` for a result. In Chrome I got `0` for a result. Likely Firefox and Chrome have different concurrency models when it comes to the `confirm` function. Firefox is likely running the modal dialog in a separate thread, allowing the `setTimeout` to continue to run in its own thread (and incrementing the value of `flag` after 200 milliseconds). Chrome is likely running the modal dialog in the same thread as `setTimeout`, thus blocking the running of the `setTimeout` (and not allowing the value of `flag` to be incremented).

Answer (score 0):

What?  You *set* flag to 10.  Why would you expect it to be 0?

Comment: How does the timer event happen while the "click" event loop is still active?

Comment: *"Why would you expect it to be 0?"* Because on Chrome, IE, and I think Safari, it's `0`. `confirm` is one of the built-in stop-the-world modals. Except on Firefox.